# Tracert of a spoofed IP results in Infinite Loop

Tags: security, routing, ip, networking

Our firewall picked up a spoofed IP address that caught my attention.  When I did a tracert to the spoofed IP address I get what I think is an odd response.

```
Tracing route to 192.168.1.7

 1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  serviceprovider1.com [24.1.1.1]
 2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  serviceprovider2.com [70.1.1.1]
 3   121 ms   122 ms   120 ms  172.28.255.254
 4   124 ms   121 ms   121 ms  172.28.1.4
 5   238 ms   242 ms   237 ms  172.28.255.254
 6   242 ms    13 ms    16 ms  172.28.1.4
 7     2 ms     2 ms     4 ms  172.28.255.254
 8    47 ms    45 ms    43 ms  172.28.1.4
```

The spoofed IP appears to hop off of our network, but then results in that weird loop.  Could this be caused by an infected machine in our network?

Comment: I wouldn't expect serviceprovider1 to forward that packet out to public IP address space, since its RFC1918. They should actually be blackholing. Is serviceprovider1.com specifically designed in your case to forward 192.168.0.0/16 packets, or do you do any natting?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about routing, but there are some NAT policies in place... so yes?

Comment: Is you're local address on the same subnet as this address?

Comment: 192.168? yes it is.

Comment: To clarify, your local network is 192.168.0.0/16, not 192.168.0.0/24?

Comment: It is a /24 block.

Comment: Please update your question with  your network configuration and routing tables.

Comment: @MatthewIfe I will do that -- but it may take a bit.  Thanks.

Comment: 1. What is your network address? Is it 192.168.1.0/24?

2. Your router shouldn't be forwarding that traffic if that ip address is local.

3. If you ping that ip address do you get a TTL Expired In Transit message?

Comment: 1. yes, i believe so. 2. That is really what is odd. 3.) yes.

Comment: Take a look at the routing table and the ARP table on the router. Can you post those here?